# Vue js unescape only certain HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, escaping

I'm using `v-html` to unescape Html tags But I only want to unescape `<a></a>` tag in a string. For an example

**Input:**

```
<p> Hello World </p> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a> <div></div>
```

**Output: *Link is active but all the other tags should be plain text***

```
<p> Hello World </p> https://www.google.com/ <div></div>
```

How can I unescape only the link tags and leave the other tags plain in Vue?

Comment: `v-html` doesn't escape HTML at all, in fact it does the opposite. Please give proper examples of your strings, how you're currently using them and what you expect the result to be

Comment: You'd probably want something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sanitize if this is user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those times where it's probably just easiest to use a regex to replace all the `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` except those around `<a>` tags

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    input: `<p> Hello World </p> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a> <div></div>`
  }),
  computed: {
    output: ({ input }) => input
      .replace(/<(?!\/?a( |>))/g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/(?<=&lt;[^>]+)>/g, "&gt;")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-html="output"></div>
  <pre>output = {{ output }}</pre>
</div>
```

The two replacements are

1. Replace any `<` that is not part of `<a>` or `</a>` with `&lt;`
2. Replace any `>` that is now preceded by `&lt;` with `&gt;`

Note that lookbehind assertions don't currently work in any version of Safari.

Answer (score -2):

HTML has escape tags that you can use:

- `&lt;` (<)
- `&gt;` (>)

Using that knowledge you can easily solve your issue.

<p> Hello World </p> https://www.google.com/ <div></div>

=

`&lt;` p `&gt;` Hello World `&lt;` /p `&gt;` https://www.google.com/ `&lt;` div `&gt;` `&lt;` /div `&gt;`